# Convert columns with two parts into MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame (read from a CSV file I cannot change):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['low', 0.5, 123, 0.8, 123], 
                   ['high', 0.7, 253, 0.9, 147]], 
                  columns=['type', 'g1 v0', 'g1 v1', 'g2 v0',  'g2 v1'])
```

I would like to "split" the columns `g1 v0`, `g1 v1`, etc. in a multiindex, e.g. like:

```
                   g1            g2
            v0     v1     v0     v1
   type     
0   low    0.5    123    0.8    123
1  high    0.7    253    0.9    147
```

Basically, I want the `gx / vy` part of the column names to be put into two separate levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = df.set_index('type')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
       g1        g2     
       v0   v1   v0   v1
type                    
low   0.5  123  0.8  123
high  0.7  253  0.9  147
```

Another solution with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), `split` and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = df.drop('type', axis=1)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split(expand=True)
print (df1)
    g1        g2     
    v0   v1   v0   v1
0  0.5  123  0.8  123
1  0.7  253  0.9  147

df = pd.concat([df['type'].rename(('','type')), df1], axis=1)
print (df)
         g1        g2     
   type   v0   v1   v0   v1
0   low  0.5  123  0.8  123
1  high  0.7  253  0.9  147
```

Comment: I cannot improve on this answer!

Comment: The `set_index` + `split` method is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!